# Docker: hashicorp/boot2docker fails to download behind corporate proxy

Tags: proxy, docker, vagrant

I'm trying to configure a number of docker containers to run from vagrant, however the corporate proxy is preventing the download of boot2docker, the VM that is downloaded when Vagrant is running on an OS that doesn't support containers; the error is an SSL Verification error. My company proxy does MITM content inspection, so it replaces the HTTPS cert with it's own cert.

I've set the http_proxy (etc) environment variables and tried both config.vm.box_download_insecure and config.vm.box_download_ca_cert (with custom cacert.pem that contains the proxy cert).

This config works:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  #config.vm.box_download_insecure = "true"
  config.vm.box_download_ca_cert = "cacert.pem"
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "1024"
    vb.cpus = "2"
  end
end
```

This does not:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  #config.vm.box_download_insecure = "true"
  config.vm.box_download_ca_cert = "cacert.pem"
  config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
    d.build_dir = "../path/to/docker"
    d.has_ssh = true
  end
end
```

Has anybody got any ideas as to why it wouldn't be working?

Update:

Frederick provided a suitable workaround below, but it highlighted that I'd asked my question too quickly.

One of the features of Vagrant's docker provider is that it will automatically download boot2docker if it is required (e.g. running on Windows or OSX) when the user calls "vagrant up". So the dev in question doesn't really need to care if he needs the proxy vm or not, it'll just work.

I can instruct those on windows to manually install the box (they will have to install other dependencies like cygwin anyway), but it just makes it easier if the instructions are more uniform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try to directly add the boot2docker box directly like

```
vagrant box add --insecure hashicorp/boot2docker
```

Comment: Frederic, this works to get the image onto the machine, and then things work as normal.I realise now though that I typed my question too quickly,  should clarify that as the original "vagrant up" command was failing on the automatic download of the boot2docker. I've updated to clarify.

Comment: well honestly I thought that `vm.box_download_insecure` would have worked. did you try the parameter only without `vm.box_download_ca_cert` ?

Comment: Yes, I'd tried the insecure first and when that didn't work I tried the ca_cert. Both options work fine with the hashicorp/precise64 but neither work with the hashicorp/boot2docker when using the command vagrant up.